# How to get the bot's voice state?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a discord.py bot that can mute and unmute itself. But I dont know how to get the VoiceState of the bot.

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@bot.command()
async def unmute(ctx):
    voice_client=ctx.guild.voice_client
    channel=voice_client.channel
    if ???ctx.channel.guild.voice_state???(channel=channel, self_deaf=True):
        await ctx.channel.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_deaf=False)
        await ctx.send("Unmuted!")
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send("Error! Not muted!")
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `intents.voice_states` enabled.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default() # enabling everything apart from privileged intents (members and presences)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents%20voice#discord.Intents.voice_states)

Also, it's not `ctx.channel.guild.voice_state(...)`, it's `ctx.guild.voice_client` or `ctx.voice_client`

Comment: what? what do you mean?

Comment: as you can see i have ????? in my code if ???ctx.channel.guild.voice_state???(channel=channel, self_deaf=True):

Comment: I don't understand anything that you're saying.

Comment: also it;s `ctx.voice_client` or `ctx.guild.voice_client` not `ctx.channel.guild.voice_state`